# How to print how many times a file is repeating in all directories from another directory #bash

Tags: linux, bash

## Bash

I have to print all files and directories from a directory(as parameter) and for files, i need to print how many times this file repeats in all directories.
For example if i have:
(i used find directory)

```
directory
directory/dir1
directory/dir1/file1
directory/dir1/file2
directory/file1
```

The program should print:

```
directory
directory/dir1
directory/dir1/file1 
2
directory/dir1/file2 
1
directory/file1 
2
```

And i tried something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $*; do
    for j in `find $i`; do
        echo $j    
        if [[ -f $j ]]; then
            s=0 
            for b in `find $i | awk -F/ '{ print $NF }'`; do
                if [[ "$j | awk -F/ '{ print $NF }'" == "$b" ]]; then
                    ((s++))
                fi
            done
            echo $s
        fi
    done
done
```

but it prints:

```
directory
directory/dir1
directory/dir1/file1
0
directory/dir1/file2
0 
directory/file1
0
```

i know that the function  `if [[ "$j | awk -F/ '{ print $NF }'" == "$b" ]]`
its not working properly but i couldnt figure out a way to solve this problem and i tried many other ways, or maybe i overcomplicated this and it can be done much easier.

I hope someone can help me (with an easier solution if possible ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 basename | sort | uniq -c
      2 file1
      1 file2
```

Comment: You mentioned that you need directories, my solution doesn't cover that case. But if it works don't forget to accept my answer.

Comment: You realise that `-print0` and `-0` are pointless flags here as `sort` and `uniq` are delimiting on newlines.